How do I use gemini-pro-vision in my extension
I am creating an extension which will retrieve image from the web and then it will pass the picture to gemini-pro-vision, but I am unable to do it only with js. It is requiring node js or python, but extension is only built on JavaScript. How do I solve it?
I want to use gemini-pro-vision as an API. I want to send it to gemini and get the response.

Assuming you are using a Gemini API Key: You can use the Gemini REST API which works well with JavaScript. https://ai.google.dev/gemini-api/docs/get-started/tutorial?lang=rest However, I recommend creating a backend that interfaces with Gemini. Your browser code interfaces with your backend. Trying to do everything in the browser (no backend) has several problems including API key protection and CORS. See Linda's answer as well.

Using the Google AI SDK for JavaScript directly from a client-side app is recommended for prototyping only. For non-prototyping use cases, we strongly recommend that you call the Google AI Gemini API only server-side to keep your API key safe. If you embed your API key directly in your web app or fetch it remotely at runtime, you risk potentially exposing your API key to malicious actors.
That being said:
<html>
<body>
<!-- ... Your HTML and CSS -->

<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {    "@google/generative-ai": "https://esm.run/@google/generative-ai"
    }
    }
</script>
<script type="module">
    import { GoogleGenerativeAI } from "@google/generative-ai";

    // Fetch your API_KEY
    const API_KEY = "REDACTED";

    // Access your API key (see "Set up your API key" above)
    const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(API_KEY);

    // ...

    // The Gemini 1.5 models are versatile and work with most use cases
    const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-1.5-flash"});

    const imagePicker = document.getElementById("image-picker");
    const selectedImagesContainer = document.getElementById("selected-images");
    const compareButton = document.getElementById("compare-button");

    // Converts a File object to a GoogleGenerativeAI.Part object.
    async function fileToGenerativePart(file) {
        const base64EncodedDataPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result.split(',')[1]);
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
        return {
            inlineData: { data: await base64EncodedDataPromise, mimeType: file.type },
        };
    }

    imagePicker.addEventListener("change", async (event) => {
        const selectedFiles = event.target.files;

        // Clear previous selections
        selectedImagesContainer.innerHTML = "";
        compareButton.disabled = true; // Disable button initially

        if (selectedFiles.length !== 2) {
            alert("Please select exactly two images.");
            return;
        }

        // Display selected images
        for (const file of selectedFiles) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (event) => {
                const img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = event.target.result;
                selectedImagesContainer.appendChild(img);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }

        // Enable compare button only when two images are selected
        compareButton.disabled = false;
    });

    compareButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
        const selectedFiles = imagePicker.files;

        if (selectedFiles.length !== 2) {
            alert("Please select exactly two images.");
            return;
        }

        const descriptions = [];
        for (const file of selectedFiles) {
            const description = await DescribeImage(file);
            descriptions.push(description);
        }

        console.log("Description 1:", descriptions[0]);
        console.log("Description 2:", descriptions[1]);
        // Implement your logic to compare descriptions and identify differences (optional)

        // You can display the descriptions to the user here (optional)
    });

    async function DescribeImage(file) {
        const imagePart = await fileToGenerativePart(file);
        const prompt = "Describe this image";
        const result = await model.generateContent([prompt, imagePart]);
        const response = await result.response;
        const text = response.text();
        document.write(text);
        return text;
    }
    // ...
</script>

<input type="file" id="image-picker" accept="image/*" multiple>
<div id="selected-images"></div>
<button id="compare-button" disabled>Compare Images</button>
</body>
</html>


This code runs when i choose file from my pc but if i retrieve an image from web page (as i am building an extention I only have this option) or giving a file path of the picture it is showing the following error
try.html:1 Access to fetch at 'file:///Users/admin/Downloads/IMG_3595.jpg' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.Understand this error
/Users/admin/Downloads/IMG_3595.jpg:1

If you can figure out how to select an image from another webpage in your client side JavaScript code.  Then just send it to gemini as I have.  Your question was I want to use gemini-pro-vision as an API. I want to send it to gemini and get the response.  I showed you how to do that.
